# How to make img fit a cell when it has a wrapper div

Tags: css

Say I have a div with fixed dimensions

```
<div class="cell" style="width:150px; height:150px"></div>
```

If I want the image to be not wider and not higher than the div, but keep its original aspect ratio I can set max-height and max-width to 100%

```
<div class="cell" style="width:150px; height:150px">  
    <img src="" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%">
</div>
```

However, in my case I want the img to be wrapped in a div. The reason is, I want to place some elements on top of the image, and position them relatively to the image:

```
<div class="cell" style="width:150px; height:150px">  
    <div class="image-button-wrapper" style="position:relative">
        <img src="" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%">
        <button style="position:absolute; top:3px; right:3px"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

However once I wrap the image in a div it only respects the max-width property, but not the max height, So the image (and the wrapper) overflow the cell in vertical direction.

**possible solution:**

I read that for max-height to work I have to set the parent's height explicitly. But how would I do that, since I want its dimensions to be identical to those of the image?

While playing around with in the browser I realized that setting the wrapper width and height to "fit-content" solves it. But this is quite uncommon value. Is that the simplest solution?

I'm adding a code snippet where you can see how the max-width is obeyed while the max-height isn't

```html
    <div class="cell" style="width:150px; height:50px;border: 3px solid red">  
        <div class="image-wrapper" style="position:relative">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/62321/kitten-cat-fluffy-cat-cute-62321.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%">
            <button style="position:absolute; top:3px; right:3px; width: 10px; height:10px"></button>
        </div>
   </div>
```

I added expected result. The only difference is making the wrapper's width and height "fit-content".

```html
    <div class="cell" style="width:150px; height:50px;border: 3px solid red">  
        <div class="image-wrapper" style="position:relative; width:fit-content; height:fit-content">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/62321/kitten-cat-fluffy-cat-cute-62321.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%">
            <button style="position:absolute; top:3px; right:3px; width: 10px; height:10px"></button>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: can you add your css and fix `<button style="position:absolute; top:3px; right:3px"` it doesn't close tag

Comment: I recoomand you add jsfiddle

Comment: I added a code snippet, is that what you meant?

And did you mean I should separate the css  from the markup?

Comment: I mean you didn't close button tag `<button></button>`

Comment: you want the image same size as `cell` and button on image or near????

Comment: I wan't it to be not bigger than the image, but to keep aspect ratio so possibly smaller. I edited to clearify

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-image`:

```css
.cell{
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/62321/kitten-cat-fluffy-cat-cute-62321.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="cell" style="width:150px; height:50px;border: 3px solid red">  
        <div class="image-wrapper" style="position:relative">

      <button style="position:absolute; top:3px; right:3px; width: 10px; height:10px">
        </button>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please see the expected result I added now in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```css
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.image-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell" style="width:150px; height:50px;border: 3px solid red">  
        <div class="image-wrapper" style="position:relative;">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/62321/kitten-cat-fluffy-cat-cute-62321.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" style>
            <button style="position:absolute; top:3px; right:3px; width: 10px; height:10px"></button>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Is this what you wanted??

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved in many ways, it depends on what you prefer.

What you did is already correct, just add `height: 100%;` to the image-wrapper:

```
<div class="cell" style="width:150px; height:50px;border: 3px solid red">  
    <div class="image-wrapper" style="position:relative; height: 100%;">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/62321/kitten-cat-fluffy-cat-cute-62321.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%">
        <button style="position:absolute; top:3px; right:3px; width: 10px; height:10px"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Explanation: The image-wrapper div has width of 100% (by default, since div is a block and blocks have default width of 100%) but no specific height. When you set height for wrapper to 100%, it considers its parent's height (the cell's height), so then, the image will respect its parent height (the image-wrapper's height).

Comment: Thank you. The problem is I do want the wrapper to be the same dimensions as the image, so when I put a button at the corner it's the corner of the image rather than the cell. That's actually the only reason I put a wrapper. Please see the expected result I added in my edit now.